# process data csv with Java 8 and streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm learning java 8 and im trying to process a csv file in java;

```
List<Catalogo> catalogos = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("src\\main\\resources\\productos.csv"), Charset.forName("Cp1252"))) {
        List<String[]> data = lines.map(s -> s.split(","))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        createCatalog(catalogos, data);
        catalogos.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void createCatalog(List<Catalogo> catalogos, List<String[]> data) {
    for (String[] x : data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            Catalogo catalogo = new Catalogo();
            catalogo.setCodigo(x[0]);
            catalogo.setProducto(x[1]);
            catalogo.setTipo(x[2]);
            catalogo.setPrecio(x[3]);
            catalogo.setInventario(x[4]);
            catalogos.add(catalogo);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to improve this code, I did not like it the way I have done it;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly map to your object using a constructor that accepts all your attributes such as :

```
try...
    List<Catalogo> catalogos = lines.map(s -> s.split(","))
            .map(s -> new Catalogo(s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
catch...
```

where the constructor based on existing code would be of signature:

```
Catalogo(String codigo, String producto, String tipo, String precio, String inventario)
```